# Cordova statusbar error - Deprecated attempt to access property 'userAgent' on IOS

Tags: javascript, ios, iphone, cordova

I'm getting a Cordova statusbar javascript error after I build an IOS project. I created a simple test that produces the error.

Steps followed:

1) Create a new project with cordova create.

2) Add the ios platform with cordova platform add ios

3) Add the statusbar plugin with cordova plugin add org.apache.cordova.statusbar

4) Run the emulator with cordova emulate ios

5) See the error in the Safari dev tools console.

> Deprecated attempt to access property 'userAgent' on a non-Navigator
>   object. #statusbar.js:99

Does anyone know how to fix this error? My computer is a mac and I'm using these versions.

cordova --version
4.0.0

cordova platform
Installed platforms: ios 3.6.3

cordova plugins
org.apache.cordova.statusbar 0.1.8 "StatusBar"

Comment: I'm having the same issue with Vibration plugin.